# Still have to login after testing SSH connection

Tags: git, ssh, zsh

I was testing my SSH connection.
After attempting to ssh to github: `$ ssh -T git@github.com` I got the following message:
`Hi Parsa237! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

I thought that it means I won't have to provide my username and password everytime I do a command like `git pull`.
Yet when I did `git pull` I still had to give my username and password.

Also my SSH key on github was never used:

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `git remote -v` ?

Comment: nope. Doesn't work. Tells me to fetch or push

Comment: `git remote -v` is not a fix, it's a command to display your remotes. Hint: verify that your remotes use SSH protocol and not HTTPS because HTTPS doesn't use SSH keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
git remote -v
```

If it's set to https change it to ssh like so:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repository.git
```

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to tell as there can be several reasons. One I stumbled across once was that if you're not using a standard name for the ssh key like id_rsa you have to specify that in the ~/.ssh/config file.

See this link for further info: https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996